# How to update a record in selected excel data sheet using VBA when there are multiple data sheets

Tags: excel, vba, record

I have a data entry form and multiple data sheets named as Table1 and Table2.I want to modify data in a particular row in the selected datasheet using data entry form. In the data entry form, there are two buttons called SAVE and MODIFY buttons. First there is a option to select a table that I want to save data. Then I click modify button and it asks us to enter the serial number to make the modification. When I  enter serial no of particular row in selected data sheet, all the details of that particular row should be appeared on the data entry form  to modify and save it to the same row using SAVE button. But it gives a error mentioning that "no record found" and it can not detect the selection of datasheets. The VBA code that  I have used for MODIFY button is given below. Please help me solve this problem sir.

```
Sub ModifyRecord()    
    Dim shTable As Worksheet
    Dim shForm As Worksheet    
    Dim iCurrentRow As Integer    
    Dim sTableName As String

    Set shForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")    
    sTableName = shForm.Range("H7").Value    
    Set shTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sTableName)    
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim iSerial As Long
    iSerial = Application.InputBox("Please enter Serial Number to make 
    modification.", "Modify", , , , , , 1)

    On Error Resume Next    
    irow = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError _
    (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSerial, 
    Sheets("sTableName").Range("A:A"), 0), 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If irow = 0 Then   
        MsgBox "No record found.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Record"
        Exit Sub        
    End If  
    Sheets("Form").Range("L1").Value = irow
    Sheets("Form").Range("M1").Value = iSerial    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H9").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    2).Value    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H11").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    3).Value  
    Sheets("Form").Range("H13").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    4).Value    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H15").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    5).Value   
    Sheets("Form").Range("H17").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    6).Value    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H19").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    7).Value     
    Sheets("Form").Range("H21").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    8).Value    
    Sheets("Form").Range("H23").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
    9).Value  
   
End Sub
```

Comment: For troubleshhoting purposes remove `On Error...` and `Iferror` clauses. You can also check your input with `Debug.Print iSerial, Typename(iSerial)`. You may need to check the data type in column A: if the data type is text then `MATCH` will not find it as an explicit  number.

Comment: can you please suggest the code for this?

Comment: The data type in column A is not a text. It is a integer

Comment: As yur post has been edited since yesterday pls dismiss my previous comment. The most recent observation is that `... Sheets("sTableName").Range(...` is a wrong reference for `sTableName` is supposed to be a variable, not a constant, so remove the quotes around and give it a try. BTW the preceeding `On Error Resume Next` hides this bug that refers to a supposedly nonexistent sheet. To unhide this kind of traps either simply comment out the `On Error...` line for the period of debugging, or run the code step by step with F8 and `Watch` Err.Number`

Comment: when I use "Table1" instead "sTableName" it only gives Table1 details. When I use "Table2" instead "sTableName" it only gives Table2 details.so what should I use instead "sTableName".can you please solve this problem sir.

Comment: That's exactly how it is supposed to work. `Sheet("Table1")` represents the sheet with name "Table1" while `Sheet(sTableName)` represents a sheet whose name is stored in variable `sTableName`. When you change the value stored in a variable, `Sheet(sTableName)` will represent another sheet.

Comment: so what should be the code if I  want to do the selection  of tables and modify the particular row in that selected data sheet. please help me sir

Comment: The answer is in my previous comment. Please note that this forum is a not a free homework writing service.

Comment: if you can't answer a problem correctly, what is the purpose of giving unsuitable answers here.it sucks.